# How to add a list of class objects to a class?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have 3 classes: House, Apartment and Resident. Each class has basic properties like string name. The question is how to create links between them like these:

### 1. House class should have Apartment property (Apartments as List (?) because one House can have multiple apartments)

### 2. Apartment class with property House (single) (the house in which the apartment is located). Also collection (list?) of Resident (people who live in the apartment).

### 3. Resident class with Apartment (single) property.

I have created a structure of these classes using inheritance, but it doesn't work - can't create House without specifying Apartment,can't add Apartment without House and so on.

```
public class House
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public List<Apartment> apartments = new List<Apartment>();
}
public class Apartment:House
{
    public int apt_number { get; set; }
    public int apt_Rooms { get; set; }
    public House house;
    public List<Resident> residents = new List<Resident>();
}
public class Resident
{   public string name {get;set;}
    public string surname {get;set}
    public Apartment apartment {get;set}
}
```

Comment: Why does `Apartment` inherit from `House`?. Does an Apartment have a street and contain other apratments?

Comment: As said above - unless you change access modifiers to the properties of `House`, you shouldn't inherit from it - otherwise the logic is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, there is (seemingly) no use in making Apartment inherit House. If you remove the inhertance, you can make some Apartment objects with a reference to a House object and add these to the Apartment list in house.

```
House house = new House();
Apartment app1 = new Apartment { house = house };
Apartment app2 = new Apartment { house = house };
Apartment app3 = new Apartment { house = house };

house.apartments = new List<Apartment>{ app1, app2, app3 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Inheretiance is not the same as composition. When you inherit a `B` from `A`, you say "`B` *is* an `A`". In your case, when you inherit `Apartment` from `House`, you are saying "An `Apartment` is a `House`". That is obviously not true, since an apartment is not a house, it is *a part of* a house. So `Apartment` shouldn't inherit from `House`.

The relationship of *being a part of* is expressed by composition. You have done that by adding a list of apartments to `House` (and a `House` property to `Apartment`).

However, you normally want to maintain integrity between the parent's list and the child's parent property. For example when you add an `Apartment`to `House`, you want the `Apartment.House` to be set accordingly.

This behavior can not be accomplished with `List<T>`. Actually `List<T>` is not made to be exposed as a public property of this kind, but for internal data storage. For your purposes you need a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` that allows the customization you need.

This is how it would work for the relationship between `House` and `Apartment`. You need to do the same for `Apartment` and `Resident`:

```
public class House
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public ApartmentCollection Apartments { get; private set; }

    public House() {
        Apartments = new ApartmentCollection(this);
    }
}

public class Apartment
{
    private House house;

    public int AptNumber { get; set; }
    public int AptRooms { get; set; }
    public House House {
        get {
            return house;
        }
        set {
            house?.Apartments.Remove(this);
            house = value;
            house?.Apartments.Add(this);
        }
    }
    public List<Resident> Residents = new List<Resident>();
}

public class ApartmentCollection : Collection<Apartment> {
    private readonly House parent;

    public ApartmentCollection(House parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Apartment item) {
        if (item == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        }
        if (Contains(item)) {
            return;
        }

        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        item.House = parent;
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, Apartment item) {
        if (item == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        }

        Apartment oldItem = this[index];
        if (oldItem.Equals(item)) {
            return;
        }

        int oldIndexOfItem = IndexOf(item);
        base.SetItem(index, item);
        oldItem.House = null;
        item.House = parent;

        //If the item was in the collection before, remove it from its old position
        if (oldIndexOfItem >= 0) {
            base.RemoveItem(oldIndexOfItem);
        }
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index) {
        Apartment removedItem = this[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        removedItem.House = null;
    }

    protected override void ClearItems() {
        Apartment[] removedItems = new Apartment[Count];
        CopyTo(removedItems, 0);
        base.ClearItems();
        foreach(Apartment removedItem in removedItems) {
            removedItem.House = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do both set `Apartment.House` or add and remove items from `House.Apartments`. The other side will always be automatically updated. Additionally, the `ApartmentCollection` will prevent adding the same apartment twice or adding a `null` value to the collection of apartments. A `List<T>` does neither.

Answer (score 0):

Sefe asks a good question regarding your classes.

You should not make Apartment inherit from House.

This concept makes more sense if you have let's say a class "Fruit" with properties. Then you have some specific classes like "Apple" or "Pear" which inherit from "Fruit". They all share the same properties of Fruit and also bring their own.

To fix your specific issue: you forgot some ';' and I removed the inheritance.
Also you have not specified get or set for the lists or the property house inside Apartment. To create variables of the classes see the post above from Aars93.

```
public class House
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public List<Apartment> apartments = new List<Apartment>();
}

public class Apartment
{
    public int apt_number { get; set; }
    public int apt_Rooms { get; set; }
    public House house;
    public List<Resident> residents = new List<Resident>();
}

public class Resident
{   public string name {get;set;}
    public string surname {get;set;}
    public Apartment apartment {get;set;}
}
```